# Jquery : Checkbox not getting checked in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check a checkbox, i've tried doing the following :-

1. `$('#someId').attr('checked','checked');`
2. `$('#someId').attr('checked', true);`

both the above work for ie8,ff **but not for ie7**!!

I'm using an older version of jquery (1.4.2) so using .prop() is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always go the native Javascript way:

```
// Get element using jQuery
var myCheckbox = $('#someId').get(0);

// Make it checked old school style.
myCheckbox.checked = true;
```

Edit:

Of course: document.getElementById("someId") will get you the element totally jQuery independend

Comment: well if you're going native, might as well go all the way... `var myCheckbox = document.getElementById("someId")`

Comment: thanks this worked fine, i think i need to brush up my basic javascript. This jquery dojo mojo :P has messed up my head :P